# Cosa significa "bari" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho trovato la frase seguente:

> I troll di Wòlstrìtt, **bari**, giocatori, puttanieri e usurai.

Non capisco il significato di "bari" in questo passaggio. Ho pensato che il singolare fosse "bario", ma, secondo i dizionari, questo è un elemento chimico,  cosa che non sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Qualcuno di voi ne sa qualcosa?

Comment: Il contesto suggerisce il plurale; i nomi in *-o* fanno, al pari dei nomi in *-io* (con *i* non tonica o muta), il plurale in *-i*: *panno*, *panni*; *cambio*, *cambi*; *gancio*, *ganci*. Quindi *bari* può essere il plurale tanto di *baro* quanto di *bario*. Il secondo non può essere, dunque è il primo. Nota che, se la *i* è tonica, rimane: *zio*, *zii*; *addio*, *addii*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bari* è il plurale di *baro*, vale a dire una persona che bara al gioco (tipicamente il gioco delle carte):

> **baro** s. m. [prob. dalla forma di nominativo del lat. *baro -onis* «briccone, cialtrone»]. – Chi bara al gioco delle carte, e in genere truffatore, imbroglione. Anticam. anche agg., in senso fig., nella locuz. *lingua bara*, gergo della malavita: *queste parole che ... fanno parte ... del gergo furbesco e della lingua b. e furfantina* (Giusti).
>
> (Dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/baro/))